# Gooey from argument to read file

Tags: python-3.x

So the first argument is the file to open and the second argument is the pattern (or text) to search for.

The program is made to scan a document and find items equal to "Pattern" and print the detector address in "DetectorPattern". I got this program working without Gooey but i thought about adding it for ease of use. My problem lies when the argument get passed to the "with open(filename)" line.

This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haral/Google Drive (synkroniseres ikke)/Programmering/Programmer/LogSearch/LogSearchGooey.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\haral\PycharmProjects\AutomateBoringStuff\venv\lib\site-packages\gooey\python_bindings\gooey_decorator.py", line 134, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/haral/Google Drive (synkroniseres ikke)/Programmering/Programmer/LogSearch/LogSearchGooey.py", line 27, in main
    with open(filename, 'r') as reader:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Namespace
```

---

```
import os
import re
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser


pattern = ""
# Chosen search pattern
detectorPattern = re.compile(r'\d\d\.\d\d\d')
# Fire alarm detector pattern, etc. 03.040
filename = ""
foundDetector = []
@Gooey
def main():
    parser = GooeyParser(description="Testing")
    parser.add_argument(
        "Filename",
        help="Choose a file",
        widget="FileChooser"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "store",
        help="Choose a pattern to search for"
    )
    filename = parser.parse_args()


    with open(filename, 'r') as reader:
        # Read and print the entire file line by line
        for line in reader:
            findLine = re.search(pattern, line)
            if findLine is not None:
                mo = detectorPattern.search(findLine.string)
                mog = mo.group()
                if mog not in foundDetector:
                    foundDetector.append(mog)

    for x in foundDetector:
        print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What is the problem ? Are there errors ? What is your expected and actual output ?

Comment: I get a error updated the main thread.

Comment: the correct path is `filename.Filename` as you have named the path user specifies as `Filename` in `parser.add_argument()`

Comment: so `with open(filename.Filename, "r") as reader:`